# ¿Cómo le puedo asignar un porcentaje a una variable?

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, jpanel

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java que te pondrá rutinas de ejercicios, todo esto dependiendo de la cantidad de tiempo que quieras hacer pero necesito que los ejercicios se dividan entre el tiempo que el usuario desee.

Si quiero hacer 30 minutos de ejercicio que los 5 ejercicios se dividan entre los 3 minutos y aparezcan en el label que asigné conforme vaya corriendo el tiempo.

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        centesimas_Segundos++;

        if (centesimas_Segundos == 100) {
            segundos++;
            centesimas_Segundos = 0;
        }
        if (valor == 1 && centesimas_Segundos == 1 && segundos == 0 && minutos == 0 && horas == 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Caminar");
        }
        if (valor == 1 && centesimas_Segundos == 1 && segundos == 0 && minutos == 1 && horas == 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Trotar");
        }
        if (valor == 1 && centesimas_Segundos == 1 && segundos == 30 && minutos == 1 && horas == 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Correr");
        }
        if (valor == 1 && centesimas_Segundos == 1 && segundos == 0 && minutos == 9 && horas == 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Trotar");
        }
        if (valor == 1 && centesimas_Segundos == 1 && segundos == 30 && minutos == 9 && horas == 0 && Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Correr");

        }
        if (valor == 1 && segundos == 60) {
            minutos++;
            segundos = 0;
        }
        if (minutos == 60 && tiempoaMin > 60) {
            horas++;
            minutos = 0;
        }
        if (valor == 1 && segundos == 0 && minutos == tiempoaMin && horas == 0) {
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Finalizado, buen trabajo!");
            BarraProgreso.setValue(x + 12);
            tiempo.stop();
            btn_iniciar.setEnabled(true);
            btn_pausar.setEnabled(false);
            btn_detener.setEnabled(false);
            txtTiempo.setEnabled(true);
            txtNombre.setEnabled(true);
            txtID.setEnabled(true);
            txtID.setText("");

            txtNombre.setText("");
            txtNombre.setText("");
            btn_iniciar.setText("Iniciar");
        }
        if (minutos == 60) {
            horas++;
            minutos = 0;
        }
        if (horas == 24) {
            horas = 0;
        }
        ActualizarEtiquetaTiempo();
    }
};
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estaría bien que cargues el código.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, ¿quieres dividir el tiempo que el usuario quiera entrenar entre cinco? ¿sin que una rutina tenga más peso que otra?

En ese caso, lo que haría es dividir el tiempo de entrada entre cinco y ese resultado asignárselo a cada rutina para obtener el total.

Por un lado, el código creo que lo puedes simplificar y mejorar, porque no dice mucho lo que hace, por ejemplo:

```
        if(Integer.parseInt(txtTiempo.getText()) <= 10 && valor == 1 && 
        centesimas_Segundos == 1 && horas == 0){
        
         if (segundos == 0) {
            if (minutos == 0) {
                etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Caminar");
            }
            if (minutos == 1 || minutos == 9) {
                etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Trotar");
            }
        }else if (segundos == 30 && (minutos == 1 || minutos == 9)){
                etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Correr");
            
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado, dividir el problema siempre suele funcionar, primero calcula el tiempo asignado a cada rutina a través del tiempo que te dé el usuario, luego, cuando tengas ese tiempo dividido entre las rutinas controla con bloques esas rutinas.

Por cierto, en realidad tienes tres rutinas (caminar, trotar y correr) no cinco, puesto que realizas las mismas varias veces.
Tal vez sería buena idea plantear una rutina de ejercicio "running" que se componga de una combinación de "formas" o "ejercicios" (caminar, trotar, correr) ejecutados en un orden especifico, el cual tu programa predefina por, tal vez, niveles de dificultad del ejercicio.

Espero que sea de ayuda, un saludo